# Add extra rows representing each month based on a date column

Tags: sql, presto

I have to create extra rows based on a created date that belongs to another table.

Table A

```
|id|createddate|type|
|1 |01/02/2020 |X   |
|1 |05/03/2020 |X   |
```

Table B

```
|id|invoicedate|amount|
|1 |01/01/2020 | 50   |
|1 |01/02/2020 | 30   |
```

Desirable outcome

```
|id|invoicedate|amount|
|1 |01/01/2020 | 50   |
|1 |01/02/2020 | 30   |
|1 |05/03/2020 | 30   |
```

Would you be able to assist me on how to achieve it? Thanks in advance

Comment: How did `1 |05/03/2020 |X ` turn into `1 |05/03/2020 | 30 `? What have you tried and what is not working for you?

Comment: I need to duplicate the values from the previous value in Table B if the created date in the table A is greater then the invoice date in table B.

Comment: This is what I tried  
SELECT *
   FROM add_next_month n
   LEFT JOIN (
   select
   *, 
   from salesforce.sf_account_history
   where field = 'Sys_Billing_Status__c'
    ) h ON "substr"(h.accountid, 1, ("length"(h.accountid) - 3)) = n.sf_account_id and invoice_date < createddate

Comment: Can table b have several records for the same id and date?

Comment: Why would an invoice amount be placed against 05/03/2020 if no invoice was on that day, and the sum of amount increases: original(50+30=80) new(50+30+30=110) which is misleading and may lead to reporting errors, Adding the extra rows is ok, but cooking the amount seems wrong

Comment: It makes sense., so I will pick only the row without extra information. Thanks a mill

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On provided data needed result can be achieved using full join and [`lag`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/window.html#lag) window function:

```sql
--sample data
WITH tableA(id, createddate) AS (
    VALUES (1, '01/02/2020'),
        (1, '05/03/2020')
),
tableB(id, invoicedate, amount) AS (
    VALUES (1, '01/01/2020', 50),
        (1, '01/02/2020', 30)
)

-- sample query
SELECT id, invoicedate,
    coalesce(amount, lag(amount) over (partition by id order by invoicedate)) amount
FROM(
    SELECT coalesce(a.id, b.id) id,
        coalesce(a.createddate, b.invoicedate) invoicedate,
        amount
    from tableA a
    FULL OUTER JOIN tableB b on a.id = b.id and a.createddate = b.invoicedate
)
```

Output

| id | invoicedate | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/01/2020 | 50 |
| 1 | 01/02/2020 | 30 |
| 1 | 05/03/2020 | 30 |